# MySQL stored procedure: How to compare two numbers and incrementally count the counter with the higher number

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

How can I compare two values from two different tables, and incrementally count the table which has the higher score?

I'm getting the error "Syntax error: unexpected '@count1' (at text suffix)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE scoreComparison()
Begin
SET @count1 := 0;
SET @count2 := 0;
IF((SELECT sum(score) from group1) > (SELECT sum(score) from group2)) THEN
    (@count1 := @count1 +1);
    ELSE
    @count2 := @count2 + 1;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? A better explanation, along with sample data and expected results would make your question clearer and increase your chances of getting an helpful answer.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Every changing of a Variable has to be done as a SET

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE scoreComparison()
Begin
SET @count1 := 0;
SET @count2 := 0;
IF((SELECT sum(score) from group1) > (SELECT sum(score) from group2)) THEN
        SET @count1 := @count1 +1;
    ELSE
        SET @count2 := @count2 + 1;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```